# Create link dynamically in customer account navigation

Tags: navigation, layout-update

I want to create a link **dynamically** in customer_block_account_navigation (link supposed to show up in the sidebar)

A static link isn't a problem, you can achieve that with a xml layout update:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
            <name>mymodulename</name>
            <path>mypath</path>
            <label>Label of the link</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

The link goes to a custom form which supposed to show up only for certain customer. So I need to control the link (or layout update) via PHP in my own module. But I couldn't find any solution how to do that.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: see the template for `customer_account_navigation` block

Comment: Thank you! I ended up by overwriting the addLink function of the class _Block_Customer_Account_Navigation (in my own extension). In the new function I'm gonna filter the concerning link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a block inside the `customer_account_navigation` and in that block, add the link to the parent block if your conditions are satisfied.

So in your layout goes this:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block type="[module]/customer_link" as="[module]_customer_link" name="[module]_customer_link">
            <action method="addLinkToParentBlock" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

And your block class shoud look like this:

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Customer_Link extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract 
{
    public function addLinkToParentBlock() 
    {
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parent) {
            if (your condition goes here) {
                $parent->addLink(
                    'Label goes here',
                    'Url goes here',
                    'title goes here',
                );

            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This way, your block will get instantiated. It will have no output, but the method `addLinkToParentBlock` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

That really depends what you want with your dynamic link. You could do a few things:

1. Rewrite `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` and change the `getLinks` function to add your link where ever you need,
2. Rewrite `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` and change the `addLink` function to add your link with the information created dynamically,
3. You could even listen to the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` check the block type and then change the links here,

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for admin Navigation

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"> <name>my_customadmin</name><path>mypath/mycustomadmin/</path><label>My Custom Navigation</label></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```